# How to redirect EE site to www. using htaccess & keep the index.php file removed

Tags: ee2, htaccess

We are running an EE site which is successfully stripping the /index.php from the URL using the following rewrite rule:

RewriteCond $1 !^(docs|index.php|sitemap.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I now need to get the site to redirect from the non www (example.com) version to the www. (www.example.com) version of the site. At the moment I've tried:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(docs|index\.php|sitemap\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This adds the 'www.', but puts the index.php back on all pages of the site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your htaccess file look like? I'm useing this at the moment `RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` And this strips www. of the URL. But I want to add www. Using your code causes redirections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the order of your RewriteRules.
i. e. put the addition of the www before the removal of the index.php.

Answer (score 2):

This is the .htaccess we use for clients who request the www.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Using your code causes in my setup `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Don't understand why...